# Is it possible to ignore a subfolder (e.g. node_module) in the mounted Volume in a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am now working on a nodejs project. There are too many small files in the node_modules folder. I want to move a docker-based development environment, so that the node_modules folder can be kept in the docker image (update when necessary). At the same time, I need the source folder of the app remain on the hosting environment. The following is the Docker file, I hoped to work:

```
FROM node
MAINTAINER MrCoder

// To simplify the process node_modules is installed and cached
ADD package.json /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN npm install

// will be mapped to the local app source folder
VOLUME /opt/app

// This is to test whether local node_modules or the folder in the image is used
CMD ls node_modules
```

Apparently, when I change add any file in the local node_modules folder it is listed.

Comment: Do you know the .dockerignore? The doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#the-dockerignore-file

Comment: I don't recommend using the mounted node_modules because many node modules are compiled to work specifically on the platform you're on. You'll get a lot of binary compatibility errors if you try to reuse compiled modules from 2 different platforms.

Comment: Hi @AbdullahJibaly, good point. I have made some change to the Dockerfile to installed it in the image rather than ADDing from the host.

Comment: This doesn't look right. Can you explain what your workflow is and what you're trying to accomplish? I'm assuming this is mainly geared around development workflow right? What does your dev environment look like?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't skip some files when mounting a volume. This is a general Linux (and every other system I know of) limitation, not Docker-related.

However, it's pretty easy to work around it: have a root-level `index.js` (or whatever) that does nothing but `require('./src');`. Then have `/opt/app` be provided by your container and mount `/opt/app/src` as an external volume.

Answer (score -1):

You could potentially use a bind mount i.e.

```
mkdir -p /node_modules
mount --bind /node_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

after the volume declaration but before the npm install.